# How to use atharva ved mantra?

Tags: vedas, mantras, atharva-veda

I want to know how to use some atharva ved mantra which is related to health? Is it any special vidi to use them?

Comment: It is best to learn from a brahmin priest of the atharva veda and schooled in the proper pronunciation of the mantras. Pronouncing the mantras wrong can yield the opposite effect. This is already answered in another question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because these type of questions should be learnt from a guru or a person who are well versed in vedas **directly not from the internet.**